# Adding all buttons captions automatically to string grid

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

I am new to Delphi. I would like to know, is there any way to add any `Caption` or `Text` inserted/created by the user in a Form to a StringGrid automatically?

For example, using for a simple translator VCL, the Form detects a Button added and the Caption of this new Button automatically appears in the StringGrid to go for the translating process.

```pascal
unit frmTranslation_u;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.Grids;

type
  TfrmTranslation = class(TForm)
    pnlPersonalInformation: TPanel;
    lblFirstName: TLabel;
    lblSureName: TLabel;
    edtFirstName: TEdit;
    edtSurName: TEdit;
    pnlAction: TPanel;
    btnEnglish: TButton;
    btnAfrikaans: TButton;
    btnDisplay: TButton;
    bmbReset: TBitBtn;
    bmbClose: TBitBtn;
    memResult: TMemo;
    sgdData: TStringGrid;
    procedure btnAfrikaansClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnEnglishClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnDisplayClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure bmbResetClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sgdDataClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmTranslation: TfrmTranslation;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmTranslation.bmbResetClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Clear the edit
  edtFirstName.Clear;
  edtSurName.Clear;
  // Clear The memo
  memResult.Clear;
  // Shift the focus to the first name edit
  edtFirstName.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TfrmTranslation.btnAfrikaansClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lblFirstName.Caption := 'Noemnaam';
  lblSureName.Caption := 'Van';
  frmTranslation.Caption := 'Vertaling';

  lblFirstName.Left := 32;
  lblSureName.Left := 80;

  btnAfrikaans.Enabled := False ;
  btnEnglish.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TfrmTranslation.btnDisplayClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // show the full name in the memo
  memResult.Lines.Add('You Added '+edtFirstName.Text +' '+ edtSurName.Text);
end;

procedure TfrmTranslation.btnEnglishClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lblFirstName.Caption := 'First Name';
  lblSureName.Caption := 'Surname';
  frmTranslation.Caption := 'translation';

  lblFirstName.Left := 40 ;
  lblSureName.Left := 50 ;

  btnEnglish.Enabled := false ;
  btnAfrikaans.Enabled := true ;
end;

procedure TfrmTranslation.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, iCol, iRow : integer ;
begin
  sgdData.Cells[0,0] := 'NAME';
  sgdData.Cells[1,0] := 'TYPE';
  sgdData.Cells[2,0] := 'Id_LAN';
  sgdData.Cells[3,0] := 'VALUE';
end;

procedure TfrmTranslation.sgdDataClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
end;

end.
```

Comment: Welcome. At runtime, you could respond to `CM_CONTROLLISTCHANGE` to intercept at `TWinControl` level (Parent), or override `Notification` to get notified at `TComponent` level (Owner). But I suspect that your question is for designtime, which requires writing and installing a ToolsAPI package wherein you implement an `IOTAIDENotifier`, something that's not typically for novice users.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow It is not clear to me if the behavior you describe is for your application at run time or when developing the application inside the IDE. Please edit your question to add details.

Comment: The IDE has a build in tool for translating strings. What's your Delphi version?

Comment: The idea is to find a solution to detect all the text like caption of labels for example automatically and put all this strings in string grid , for exapmle if i decide later to add a new button,this function automatically detect the caption and put it in string grid for translation process, i am using 10.4 version,Thanks all